# Add horizontal line in single hist plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I want to draw the median location and its value next to each bar in a set of bars.

Given the [matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/misc/table_demo.html)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = [[ 66386, 174296,  75131, 577908,  32015],
        [ 58230, 381139,  78045,  99308, 160454],
        [ 89135,  80552, 152558, 497981, 603535],
        [ 78415,  81858, 150656, 193263,  69638],
        [139361, 331509, 343164, 781380,  52269]]

columns = ('Freeze', 'Wind', 'Flood', 'Quake', 'Hail')
rows = ['%d year' % x for x in (100, 50, 20, 10, 5)]

values = np.arange(0, 2500, 500)
value_increment = 1000

# Get some pastel shades for the colors
colors = plt.cm.BuPu(np.linspace(0, 0.5, len(rows)))
n_rows = len(data)

index = np.arange(len(columns)) + 0.3
bar_width = 0.4

# Initialize the vertical-offset for the stacked bar chart.
y_offset = np.zeros(len(columns))

# Plot bars and create text labels for the table
cell_text = []
for row in range(n_rows):
    plt.bar(index, data[row], bar_width, bottom=y_offset, color=colors[row])
    y_offset = y_offset + data[row]
    cell_text.append(['%1.1f' % (x / 1000.0) for x in y_offset])
# Reverse colors and text labels to display the last value at the top.
colors = colors[::-1]
cell_text.reverse()

# Add a table at the bottom of the axes
the_table = plt.table(cellText=cell_text,
                      rowLabels=rows,
                      rowColours=colors,
                      colLabels=columns,
                      loc='bottom')

# Adjust layout to make room for the table:
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, bottom=0.2)

plt.ylabel("Loss in ${0}'s".format(value_increment))
plt.yticks(values * value_increment, ['%d' % val for val in values])
plt.xticks([])
plt.title('Loss by Disaster')

plt.show()
```

I tried to insert this in the `for` loop creating the bars

```
for row in range(n_rows):
    plt.bar(index, data[row], bar_width, bottom=y_offset, color=colors[row])
    med = np.median(data[row])
    xmin = row
    xmax= (row + 1)
    label = str(med) + "%"
    plt.hlines(med, xmin, xmax, label=label, linestyle="dashed")
    y_offset = y_offset + data[row]
    cell_text.append(['%1.1f' % (x / 1000.0) for x in y_offset])
```

**However** the lines are too long: how to get the bar width? **Plus** labels don't show up **and** bars are shifted away from the cell centers...!

[image: barplot]

Comment: You need to set `xmin` and `xmax`

Comment: I've tried but it gives one single line

Comment: Use `hlines` instead

Comment: I've updated the code to include `hline` and consequent issues

Comment: For the positioning of the bars see my answer. The point with the labels is that when using `hlines` you just get 1 label. If you add `plt.legend()` to you code, it will draw the legend and you'll see why this is not ideal. It might be better to put the actual median as `annotation` next to each bar...

Comment: Added simple example using `annotations` to my answer. Hope that helps you to get what you want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the positioning:**

I've adapted your code slightly.
The point is that `bar` draws the bars centered by default (see the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) that always helps) so you need to set the `hlines` from center - 0.5 bar width to center + 0.5 bar width:

```
# Plot bars and create text labels for the table
cell_text = []
medians = []
for row in range(n_rows):
    plt.bar(index, data[row], bar_width, bottom=y_offset, color=colors[row])
    y_offset = y_offset + data[row]
    cell_text.append(['%1.1f' % (x / 1000.0) for x in y_offset])
    medians.append(np.median(data[row]))
# Reverse colors and text labels to display the last value at the top.
colors = colors[::-1]
cell_text.reverse()
# Draw the medians
h_width = 0.5 * bar_width
plt.hlines(medians, xmin=index-0.5*bar_width, xmax=index+0.5*bar_width, color="k", linestyle="dashed", linewidth=1)
```

This is what you get then:

[image]

**Now for the labels**:

If you use `hlines` with `label=label` you still need to draw the legend with `plt.legend()`.

The issue is, however, that all values will be in the legend and it will be hard, if not impossible, to associate each value to the corresponding line, especially if they all have the same color. A better solution might be to place the values next to each dashed line. To achieve this you could use [annotations](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html):

```
# add the annotations (just after the part from above)
for i, med in enumerate(medians):
    plt.annotate(str(med) + "%", xy=(index[i], med), 
                 ha='center', va='bottom'
            )
```

So you end up with:

[image]

*Hope that helped and happy coding!*